# How to delete everything from string after character "/u"?

Tags: c#

Hi i have strange problem. Here is my code:

```
string tmp = "20_29\u0013";
```

How can I get rid of that "\u0013"?

---

Normally I will do it with substring or something but I have some issues with that character ---> \
Could someone help me?

Comment: Where did this come from? `\u0013` is an escape sequence representing the carriage return character

Comment: It is from my client which is sending data to my server. TCP\IP

Comment: technically, `tmp = tmp.Replace("\u0013", "");` where `"\u0013"` is in fact a single character with `0x0013` code: `'\r'`. Another possibility is `tmp = tmp.TrimEnd();` which removes white spaces (`'\r'` included) from the end of the string

Comment: Does the *client* send `\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `1`, `3` ? Or a single `0x13` byte? This escape sequence is a carriage return, also represented as `\r`. In all single-byte code pages *and* UTF8 it's represented by a single byte, `0x13`. You can remove it from the end of any string with `Strings.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');`

Comment: That trimEnd won't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tmp.TrimEnd('\u0013')` if it is single char or `tmp.Replace("\\u0013", string.Empty)` if it is sequence of chars to get "20_29" part:

Comment: Everything is a Unicode character. This particular character though is an ASCII character - a carriage return `\r`

Comment: Yes, I mean that '\u0013' is one solid character (not string of characters), so you can use IndexOf on it

Comment: Or use `TrimEnd`

Comment: Yes, TrimEnd is perfect choice here